# Error Failure when updating a linked SSMS table in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I've suddenly been unable to make changes (i.e. add or change data) to a SSMS linked table in MS Access 2010 after renaming a few columns. This happens both when I try to edit the table through a form and when I try to edit directly into the table in datasheet view. I could edit perfectly fine before I changed the column names.

I have refreshed the linked tables so that the new column names are showing. I have also re-inserted the new columns into the forms. However, when I try to make changes this error message comes up:

> 'ODBC - update on a linked table  failed.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'FolderName'.(#207)'

'FolderName' was the old column name, so it looks like it is still trying to find it even though it doesn't exist in the table or the forms anymore (where the new column name is showing).

I have tried refreshing the tables with a new ODBC link but this didn't work. I also closed and re-opened both SSMS and MS Access to no avail. Is this a SQL Server Driver problem and issue with the network I'm on?

Comment: How are you making changes? Are you directly opening the table in MS-Access? Perhaps there is a trigger on the table looking for that column.

Comment: Hi Nick,Yes I am directly opening the table in MS Access. There is a trigger on the table linked to an audit table, but I changed the column names in the audit table as well....I will check the trigger itself though, thanks.

Comment: Yes the trigger will refer to that column

Comment: So, yes you were right it was the audit trigger that I needed to change and update the column names in the script to the new ones. Many thanks!

Comment: It works fine now and I can make and save changes to that table :)

Answer (score 0):

So, yes you were right it was the audit trigger that I needed to change and update the column names in the script to the new ones. Many thanks! –

Thank you to @Nick.McDermaid who highlighted this as the probable answer.